# What does the tmp variable do in this code? Leetcode #94

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, inorder

new to python, I am doing leetcode problem 94, Binary Tree Inorder Traversal. Given the root of a binary tree, return the inorder traversal of its nodes' values.

I have found this code from https://leetcode-cn.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/solution/dong-hua-yan-shi-94-er-cha-shu-de-zhong-xu-bian-li/

```
class Solution(object):
    def inorderTraversal(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        res = []
        pre = None
        while root:
            if root.left:
                pre = root.left
                while pre.right:
                    pre = pre.right
                pre.right = root

                tmp = root
                root = root.left
                tmp.left = None
            else:
                res.append(root.val)
                root = root.right
        return res
```

However, I can't understand what tmp variable is doing here. It seems that the tmp variable is not used in any other places.

I tried to remove these 2 lines

```
tmp = root
tmp.left = None
```

But then I get a timeout error. Could anyone please explain what these 2 lines are doing here?

Comment: Visualise it at http://pythontutor.com…

Comment: Those three lines set `root` to `root.left`, and then unset *the old* `root.left`. You'd have a hard time unsetting *the old* `root.left` if you didn't save it in some other variable before overwriting `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the code step by step. The code wants to assign "move" `root` to the left, and then set the old `root.left` to `None`.

The two naive options fail:

```
root.left = None
root = root.left   # root.left no longer is what it used to be because of the first line
```

or:

```
root = root.left
root.left = None  # root no longer is what it used to be because of the first line
```

You can do without the `tmp` variable, however:

```
root.left, root = None, root.left
```

This works because Python evaluates the entire right hand side first, and then assigns the lhs from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

tmp is necessary to remove the left child of root, otherwise it would keep looping.